# jQuery Submenu not disappearing unless it is hovered once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="main-nav main-nav-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-nav-logo">
        <a class="logo-color" href="index.html">Centaur <span class="brand">Research</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="main-nav-links">
        <ul id="responsive">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-lists">
                    <li><a href="research_sector.html">Research Sector</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://online.c-research.in/">Online Research</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://travel.c-research.in/">Travel Research</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://panel.c-research.in">Panel</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-lists">
                    <li><a href="http://focusgroup.c-research.in/">Discussion Group</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Language</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-lists">
                    <li><div class="translate"><div id="google_translate_element"></div></div> <script type="text/javascript">
                        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                            new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-38654447-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
                        }
                    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-lists").hide();
    $(".dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown-lists").slideDown();
        $(".dropdown-lists").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
        });
    });
```

Basically the thing is that the dropdown works perfectly when I hover over it but it doesnt disappear unless I hover over the submenu thats `.dropdown-lists` class. If I hover over the `.dropdown` class and navigates away without hovering over the submenu the submenu doesn't disappear. It stays still unless I hover it over at least once.

I understand my jQuery only allows to slide the menu Up when it is hovered once, I want to know a code combination that would work even if I don't hover over the submenu.

Additionally here is the Dropdown CSS code, I doubt the the submenu somehow is not a child element of the parent main-nav-link or #responsive:

`.main-nav-links {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    }
    #responsive {
    text-align: right;
    }
    #responsive li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    #responsive li > a {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    @media (max-width: 992px){
    #responsive li > a {
    font-size: 12px;
    }
    }
    #responsive li > a:hover {
    color: #19B5FE;
    }
    .dropdown-lists {
    text-align: center;
    }
    #responsive li .dropdown-lists li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -29px!important;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(60,60,60,0.9);
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    #responsive li .dropdown-lists li > a {
    color: rgba(204,204,204,0.8);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    }
    #responsive li .dropdown-lists li > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    }
    #responsive li .dropdown-lists {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200%;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
    }`

Comment: Did you just bind the mouseleave event inside the mouseenter event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your jquery like this.

```
$(".dropdown-lists").hide();
$(".dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-lists").slideDown();

    }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-lists").slideUp();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Nh8/1/)

EDIT:

Additional problem comes for the dropdown in your latest fiddle because of the `top` property you have used in the dropdown CSS. Update the following class in your CSS.

```
#responsive li .dropdown-lists {
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 100%; /* It was 200% earlier */
background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
}
.dropdown
{
 height:40px;
}
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Nh8/2/)

Comment: Still when I hover away from the `.dropdown` the submenu closes directly and i can't even click the links of the dropdown menu. Literally it's just opening and closing directly with no waiting whether I hover over the `.dropdown-lists` class or not.

Comment: which browser? i am using chrome and i can able to click the links without any problem. may be it is very much close to each other. So you feel like that. Just give some padding between them then you can test it clearly.

Comment: Chrome.. I have added the CSS and updated the description: You can also view the functioning code here: [link](http://www.c-research.in)

Comment: I have checked out now, using 100% top value does solve the issue but the submenu is going above the navbar I mean its overlapping. I have the navbar at height 60px so when I apply 100% top value the submenu starts straight down the parent menu not from below the navbar main.. ANd if I put margin-top .. The same thing happens again like previous.

Comment: instead of margin use padding.

Comment: Attached is the [Screenshot](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/571x215q90/822/vyzh.png)

Comment: I checked your site. you need to add one class. I have updated in my answer. check that one.

Comment: AAAh at last it worked... 40px height was all that I need .. many Many thanks brother..